# Laravel 5.2 - Query Builder Syntax To Filter Polymorphic Relationship?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have the following query where I want to filter a polymorphic relationship:

```
$companyLogo = $user->company->files->where('file_type', 'Logo')->first();
```

When I enable the query log this is what I get:

```
"query" => "select * from `files` where `files`.`fileable_id` = ? and `files`.`fileable_id` is not null and `files`.`fileable_type` = ?"
"bindings" => array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => "App\Company"
]
```

As you can it is not including my where clause?

*** Update ***

This is the polymorhpic relationship I have between company and file models:

```
class File extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'path',
    'size',
    'mime_type',
    'file_type',
    'fileable_id',
    'fileable_type',

   ];

   public function fileable()
   {
       return $this->morphTo();
    }

}


class Company extends Model {

   public function files()
   {
       return $this->morphMany('App\File', 'fileable');
   }

 }
```

I'm not sure why the query inst including the where clause either. Is the syntax correct to filter a polymorphic relationship? A company can have different types of files e.g. documents, logo etc but I want to select the logo.

Comment: `file_type` or `fileable_type`?

Comment: Also the queries you have outputted neither bindings have `Logo`? Are you sure they are the right queries?

Comment: the queries in your log don't seem to coincide with the query in your question

Comment: @chiliNUT is my syntax correct for filtering a polymorphic relationship? The query logs are defo related to the queries. See my update.

Comment: @aynber I want to filter by file_type - see my update.

Comment: @adam78 The problem is your query log says `fileable_type` at no point in the query does it say `file_type` and at no point in the bindings does it say `Logo`, you need to get the correct query so then we can help you.

Comment: @Purgatory I've figured it out  now see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to refactor as follows:

Added a query scope to the File class:

```
public function scopeCompanyLogo($query, $id)
{
    $query->where('file_type','=', 'Logo')
        ->where('fileable_type','=', 'App\Company')
        ->where('fileable_id','=', $id);
}
```

Now get the company logo as follows:

```
 $companyLogo = File::CompanyLogo($user->company_id)->first();
```

*** Update ***

Just figured what was wrong with original code too

Instead of doing this:

```
$companyLogo = $user->company->files->where('file_type', 'Logo')->first();
```

It should have been:

```
 $companyLogo = $user->company->files()->where('file_type', 'Logo')->first();
```